# commit changes that not compiles into branch

Tags: git, svn, github, branch, commit

Suppose you have two very close to each other tasks.
Both of them forces you to make a big changes (method's signatures, for example).

The first task makes changes B and A. The second task makes changes C and A.

So if you commit B without A code will not compile, if you commit both B and A you will make a double job, because A will be rewroted in second commit.

So there is a dilemma:

1) Make both of them into one commit;

2) Make a branch, where first commit will NOT be able to compile;

3) Make them into separate commits, but do a double job.

If my explanations are not clear there is a shorter version:

Is commiting code that will fail compilation into branch (or local commit) a bad practice? Should all revisions, including ones in branches be able to compile without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the project, prevalent practises, and number of lines of code, and so is definitely opinion based.

If I was the one committing changes (usually Python), I would try to make sure that my commits working copies of code, and do not have some transient pieces.

That said, in practise, the changes can often be found across multiple files in hundreds of lines, and it will be a good strategy to commit every major chunk of code, tag the working copies with [`git tag`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging), and use the tags exclusively for deployments. The rationale being, that for a significant change, a screwup at just a small place is enough to cost you significant debugging time, that you could have spent doing development.